# SQL Server database queries in Ansible

Tags: sql-server, ansible, ansible-inventory

I would like to find out if anyone in the community has used Ansible to manipulate a Microsoft SQL Server database?

We want to add a task to our environment configuration scripts written in Ansible that will `INSERT` rows into a SQL Server table. The rows will have parameters that are specified in our variables files.

I have been unable to locate a specific Ansible module for achieving this so would like to hear if anyone has has success in some other way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For completeness here is the syntax of the solution used in Ansible to SELECT & INSERT for Microsoft SQL Server:

**INSERT**

```
- name: 'insert row to SQL server DB'
  win_shell: "invoke-sqlcmd -username \"{{db_user}}\" -password \"{{db_pass}}\" -Query \"INSERT INTO Addresses (DoorNum,Street,Town,PostCode) VALUES ({{ item.doornum }},'{{ item.street }}','{{ item.town }}''{{ item.postcode }}')\""
```

**SELECT**

```
- name: 'select from SQL server DB'
  win_shell: "invoke-sqlcmd -username \"{{db_user}}\" -password \"{{db_pass}}\" -Query \"SELECT ID FROM Addresses WHERE PostCode = '{{ item.postcode }}'\" | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty ItemArray, Table, RowError, RowState, HasErrors | ConvertTo-Json"
  register: response

- set_fact:
    ids: "{{ response.stdout|from_json}}"

- debug:
    var: ids
```

Answer (score 0):

Ansible has [db specific modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/list_of_database_modules.html) but none is available to launch queries on Microsoft SQL Server.

[`win_shell`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/win_shell_module.html) is your friend in this context.

How I see it from your scenario:

- Create a template for your queries using your vars
- Push the templated content to your server with the `template` module
- Use `win_shell` to feed that file to your mssql command line for execution.
- Eventually delete the pushed file.

Comment: I see there is ‘invoke-sqlcmd’ - win_shell should be able to drive - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps

Comment: I have now tried your suggesting of `win_shell` in Ansible to call `invoke-sqlcmd` e.g:
`- name: 'invoke sql test'`
`win_shell: "invoke-sqlcmd -username 'USERNAME' -password 'PASSWORD' -Query ''SELECT * FROM TABLENAME"`