# Set Compatibility Level while provisioning a new SQL Server 2019. Any ansible roles available to set this while running the pipeline?

Tags: sql-server, ansible, azure-pipelines

We recently migrated to SQL Server 2019 by provisioning a new VM. We would like to set the backward compatibility to true as our old server was in SQL Server 2012.

Is there any ansible role or flag available to set the backward compatibility to true while running the pipeline during SQL Server installation?

Comment: What does "backward compatibility" mean in this context?

Comment: @Deepak I assume you mean setting the compatibility level on the database to 110? Which is the level that SQL Server 2012 used by default.

Comment: @Charlieface So currently our server is SQL Server 2019. In the database properties we want to set the compatibility level to SQL Server 2012. So is there a way to make the new server backward compatible with SQL Server 2012?

Comment: @MartinBrown yes that's right. I want to set the compatibility level on the database to 110. But while installing the SQL 2019 on the new server, the Backward Compatibility has not been set. Hence 110 is not showing up on the compatibility level.

Comment: I've no idea about ansible, normally you would set this with SQL on the database rather than the server with a command like this: ALTER DATABASE database_name SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110;

Comment: This question seems to answer how to run SQL against a DB with ansible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59093991/sql-server-database-queries-in-ansible

Answer (score 0):

## Setting the compatibility level using SQL

SQL Server uses a `COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL` setting to provide backwards compatibility. Setting the compatibility level setting of SQL Server is normally applied for an individual database rather than the whole server. This can be done using an SQL Command like this:

```
ALTER DATABASE some_database_name SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110;
```

`110` is the compatibility level for SQL Server 2012. It will make the database run fairly closely to how SQL Server 2012 behaves by default, but there will be one or two subtle differences. There is a full list of compatibility levels in the [ALTER DATABASE (Transact-SQL) compatibility level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-ver16#arguments) web page.

When creating a database the server largely just copies the model database. So if you want to change the compatibility level for all databases created on that server going forwards you need to set the compatibility level on the model database like this.

```
ALTER DATABASE model SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110;
```

But this is not a recommended approach.

## Running SQL using ansible

### using win_shell and invoke-sqlcmd

Ansible does not have a built in way to manage SQL Server databases. There are various work arounds. One is to use the `win_shell:` option to run a PowerShell  command called [`invoke-sqlcommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlps/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps) that runs the SQL, something like this:

```
- name: 'Set DB compatibility level'
  win_shell: "invoke-sqlcmd -Database master -username \"{{db_user}}\" -password \"{{db_pass}}\" -Query \"ALTER DATABASE {{dbName}} SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110;\""
```

This assumes you have the [`SQLPS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/download-sql-server-ps-module?view=sql-server-ver16) or [`SqlServer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/download-sql-server-ps-module?view=sql-server-ver16) PowerShell module installed. It is probably also possible to use the [sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver16) command line command, but I'll leave that as an exercise. It is probably slightly more likely to already be installed.

### Using the microsoft.sql.server role

Another way is to use the open source [`microsoft.sql.server`](https://github.com/linux-system-roles/mssql) ansible role. Microsoft have published an article called [Deploy SQL Server – The Ansible way!](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/deploy-sql-server-the-ansible-way/ba-p/2593284) that has a fuller description. But briefly it can be done as follows.

The role has an `mssql_input_sql_file:` attribute that allows the setting of an SQL file. The file would contain any SQL Script you want to run on install. See the Setting the compatibility level using SQL section above for the commands. This can be used like this:

```
- hosts: all
  vars:
    mssql_accept_microsoft_odbc_driver_17_for_sql_server_eula: true
    mssql_accept_microsoft_cli_utilities_for_sql_server_eula: true
    mssql_accept_microsoft_sql_server_standard_eula: true
    mssql_password: "p@55w0rD"
    mssql_edition: Evaluation
    mssql_input_sql_file: my_sql_file.sql
  roles:
    - microsoft.sql.server
```

Note that SQL is not generally [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence). As such it is normally advisable to check if things exist before creating them. But there are limits, once you delete data there is no reverting that. Fortunately the database compatibility level is one of the few things that can be applied multiple times.